# For my pojo class table is not getting created in database

Tags: java

**For the below pojo class table is not getting created**

### RegistrationBean.java

```
package com.cg.uas.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "registration")
public class RegistrationBean {

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String userEmail;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "contactNo")
    private long contactNo;

    @Column(name = "userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

---

If i add @Id annotation for any of the above pojo class member then the table is being created.

Comment: Yes, entity class must have an ID column. if you add @id annotation to primary key column, the table will be created

Comment: You have to mark one property of a your bean as primary key.

Comment: why is it that compulsory to have a primary key for atleast one column ?

Comment: To make unique column @Id is required.

Comment: If i add @Id to userEmail property when executing its showing error like **"ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()"**

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
package com.cg.uas.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "registration")
public class RegistrationBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "regId")
    private long regId;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String userEmail;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "contactNo")
    private long contactNo;

    @Column(name = "userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

Comment: If i do like this table is getting created but i am facing issue when executing my web application. The problem is that my registration page is not getting opened if i add like this. Its showing like HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'reg' available as request attribute